# Updating Android Studio to version 0.8 (beta)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am current using Android Studio(Preview) 0.6.1. Can I update it to the Beta version 0.8 directly?

While trying to update Studio, it says the current version is already up to date!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your configuration of AS0.6.1 doesn't detect the update, then you have to do it manually.

As explained on the official page (https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) you could replace it with the latest version, simply be sure to save your SDK (you can know it's location in configure -> project defaults -> project structure)

Then once AS 0.8 is isntalled, just copy back your previous SDK to the new location (or change it via the settings)

I would also suggest to export your settings to be safe.

Hope it helps.